# How can I install a new stable Linux kernel without removing the older one?

Tags: software-installation, kernel

I want to install a new stable Linux kernel without removing the older one, as I see there is an option in Ubuntu to switch on whichever kernel I want to use.

Comment: Unless you have changed the Update settings, your system will automatically install new kernels (in the background). The newest kernel will become effective when you reboot. Your system will automatically retain at least one older kernel, rotating and deleting the oldest kernels after new kernels are installed. If you have not changed the default Update settings, you need do nothing - the system is already doing it for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. To get a listing of the latest packages available for upgrade use

`sudo apt-get update`

2. Instead of running `sudo apt-get upgrade` and selecting "Y" for "Yes"

use `sudo apt-get install "linux-image-###"` to install the newest version alongside the old one.

3. Make sure to select the appropriate version when at the GRUB screen.

   3b. Hold/mash `Shift` after bios boot to get the GRUB screen to load if your installation is set to skip it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to install a new kernel using Ubuntu is using the Ukuu kernel Update Utility, you can launch it from your apps amd choose to install whatever kernel version Ubuntu supports.
Each time you install a new one it creates an entry in GRUB so you can boot into an older kernel in case the new one doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This link: [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) will answer all your questions on how to install a new kernel.

You can install kernels outside your distribution chain such as `4.14.xxx LTS` which you will have to manually remove when unwanted.

Regular system updates will install new kernels from time to time. They may auto remove older kernels but will always keep the latest kernel plus the previous version for fall-back purposes in case a bug is discovered in the new version.

Ubuntu doesn't switch on the different kernel versions. You do this using grub's Advanced Options menu at boot time.